# json jquery grid (using django) - having problems presenting the data

Tags: jquery, django, jqgrid

I'm trying this source where jqGrid gets some json data from django: [link](http://code.google.com/p/django-jqgrid/)

Unfortunately the data is not presented in the jqgrid, only an empty jqgrid.

I'm rendering the jqgrid with this call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON("{% url myapp.views_json.grid_config %}", function(data){
            $("#mygrid")
                .jqGrid(data)
                .navGrid('#pager', 
                    {add: false, edit: false, del: false, view: true},
            {}, // edit options
            {}, // add options
            {}, // del options 
            { multipleSearch:true, closeOnEscape:true }, // search options 
            { jqModal:false, closeOnEscape:true} // view options 
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

{% url myapp.views_json.grid_config %} is resolved to the url "projects/examplegrid/cfg/". When I call this URL in my browser it returns JSON data. Please follow the link to see it. [json config data](http://mocaso.vs120027.hl-users.com/website/config_json_data)

This should be ok. I guess..
In this json data file you see an url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pm/projects/examplegrid/
This url returns also json data. This is the json representation of the data that I want to present. See this json data set here: [link](http://mocaso.vs120027.hl-users.com/website/sample_json_data)

Here is a screenshot of the resulting jqgrid. [link](http://mocaso.vs120027.hl-users.com/website/grid_shot.JPG)
I know it's probably tough to help me out here. But it seems to me as that my problem is on the jqgrid side and I think there are a lot of cracks outside who know who to deal with it. I do not :-)

Edit: The undefined error is gone. This error was due a missing reference to a local file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

But the next error is, that it shows "Loading" and it does not finish. Anybody knows what the problem could be?

Edit: The errow was obviously that the jqgrid was not initialised correctly. I used the wiki page proposed by CalebD and it works now. At least the json data is presented in the grid. I'm wondering now what I have to do in order to update a row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
      jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
          url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/pm/projects/examplegrid/',
          datatype: "json",
          mtype: 'GET',
          colNames:['id', 'description'],
          colModel:[
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:55, sortable:false, editable:false, editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}},
                    {name:'description',index:'description', width:300, editable:true},
               ],
         jsonReader : {
              repeatitems:false
         },
          rowNum:10,
          rowList:[10,20,30],
          pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
          sortname: 'name',
          viewrecords: true,
          sortorder: "asc",
          caption:"Wines",
          editurl:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/pm/projects/examplegrid/"
     }).navGrid('#gridpager');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for .jqGrid excepts a JS object that describes settings for the grid, not JSON data. You have to define the data type, columns, and column models, among other options. The jqGrid wiki has some examples:

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:conventions

If you scroll down, there is an example using JSON.

Comment: Ok that already helped me a lot! It works now and the data is presented. Thank you! Do you know what I have to take care of when I want to edit data from the jqgrid? I always get an error Status: ''. Error code: 0 . My question is what has to happen on the server side? Encode json data and return true?

Comment: With jqGrid you have to make sure you've downloaded a version with the specific editing options you want enabled. You can do so on the download page: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 -- server side it depends on the editing type but basically jqGrid posts the new value(s) to a specific URL and that URL is expected to return a HTTP 200 code upon success. I don't think the content of the server's response matters. Lots of info here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules

Comment: wow thanks. And is the json data in the jqgrid automatically refreshed after a successful update of a row or do I have to do some kind of callback?

Comment: I don't think jqGrid refreshes the data because if the edit was successful then the data currently in the grid, just edited by the user, should match the data on the server. You can, however, have the server return whatever you want, and use an after save event to modify the row as needed, for example if you have rows that are automatically calculated by the server. This is what I had to do to hook jqGrid up to a SharePoint list because of some calculated fields and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a row, editurl should be specified in config grid params.
In your example it is specified in js, but it also can be configured in JqGrid class.
You have to use url for handling updates the same as you have url that handles pagination, sorting,...
I'm using it in such a way:

urls.py:

```
...
(r'^jqgrid/(?P(\w+))/$', 'grid_handler', {}, 'grid_handler'),
(r'^jqgrid/cfg/(?P(\w+))/$', 'grid_config', {}, 'grid_config'),
(r'^edit-store/$', 'edit_store'),
...
```

grids.py:

```
class StoreGrid(JqGrid):
    ...
    url = '/jqgrid/StoreGrid/'
    editurl = '/edit-store/' 
    ...
```

config dictionary should have 'editurl' key, add it in get_config():

```
def get_config(self, as_json=True):
config = self.get_default_config()
    config.update({
        'url': self.get_url(),
        'editurl': self.get_editurl(), #!
        'caption': self.get_caption(),
        'custom_url': self.get_custom_url()
     })
     ...
```

views.py:

```
def grid_handler(request, grid_name):
    grid = class_for_name(grid_name, 'some_namespace.grids')()
    return HttpResponse(grid.get_json(request), mimetype="application/json")

def grid_config(request, grid_name):
    grid = class_for_name(grid_name, 'some_namespace.grids')()
    return HttpResponse(grid.get_config(), mimetype="application/json")

def edit_store(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('oper') and request.POST['oper'] == 'del':
            try:
                Store.objects.get(id=request.POST['id']).delete()
            except Exception, ex:
                logging.debug(ex)
        else:
            try:
                instance = Store.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('id'))
                instance.some_field = request.POST.get('some_field')
                instance.the_other_field = request.POST.get('the_other_field')
                instance.save()
            except Exception, ex:
                logging.debug(ex)
        return render_to_response('template.html')
    return HttpResponseNotFound('invalid request')
```